# Send a message to people that never used a bot on telegram

Tags: php, mysqli, bots, telegram

I own few telegram bots and i'm trying to find a way to make a "super bot" where I can contact everybody by sending a message from a bot or platform.

Unfortunately if a user never used a bot can't be receive any message.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're from Telegram, you cannot do it as any kind of "super bot" that you wish to make cannot contact any user unless used or authorized by user.

Just imagine what all people can send to the anyone and everyone if that was possible.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just trying to figure out what is possible to do with Telegram :)

Comment: Never mind. Pretty basic stuff though, right? :) I hope I was able to help.